# Remove matching strings using regex

Tags: regex

I have a comma-delimited list of name/value pairs like this:

```
make=mazda;model=cx-5;year=2016;moonroof=yes;radio=yes;navigation=no;color=gray;
```

I would like to remove the moonroof, radio, and navigation pairs. I can capture these pairs using a regex like this:

```
(radio|navigation|moonroof)=.*?(?:;|$)
```

Is there a way to remove the captured group(s) using regex alone, **without writing code**? Alternatively, is there a way to get the rest of the pairs excluding the captured groups?

Comment: Not that I'm aware.  But in Java, you can do String.replaceAll() with a regex and a capture number.  Replacing all with an empty string would do it.  But then, that is code.

Comment: You can capture all the non-radio etc. groups individually using a regex e.g. https://regex101.com/r/piQSID/1 but you'd still have to join them together back into a string

Comment: What is the expected result? And what language/tool are you using?

Comment: A regex just matches (or not) a pattern, it doesn't replace anything. You have to use use the proper function of your language to do a replacement, `replace`, `sub` or whatever your language propose. You can't do replacement without code.

Answer (score 0):

If your data set is small, you can use an online website to do it (such as https://regex101.com/.) With Linux or, I imagine [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) you should be able to use the above expression with sed or bash regexp:

`sed -ri 's/(radio|navigation|moonroof)=.*?(;|$)//g' <filename>`

That sed command will do it in situ, so back up your data first.

Without bash/sed/perl to help you from a suitable command line, I'm sorry to say you need code, or rather the regexp engine associated with it!!!

Hope that helps!